# Prevent repeating build.gradle android configuration on submodules?

Tags: android, gradle

How can I prevent adding these lines of code in the build.gradle for modules?

```
android {
    namespace 'androidx.compose.samples.common'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
    }
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}
```

I can see that the now in android project modules have only the namespace declaration as below:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.google.samples.apps.nowinandroid.core.common"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this directory in `nowinandroid` that handles all the gradle magic with the build process.

https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/tree/main/build-logic

This is added called in the `settings.gradle.kts` file in the this code block it has this line: `includeBuild("build-logic")`

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("build-logic")
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

The folder has all the code that is being used.